# Search the product by tag or category not working

Tags: plugin-development, search, tags

I am working on search. I am trying to search the product by tag or category. I tried below code but it's not working. I am getting

> Nothing Found

Also title and content is also not working.

Would you help me out in this?

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result
 *
 * @package CoolPickings
 */

get_header();
?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area mainSearch">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">
            <div class="equalPadding">
                <div class="cp-seeWrapper">
        <?php 

        $getSearch=get_search_query();

    $args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $getSearch
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $getSearch
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'product'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
                    get_search_form();//search form 
                    ?>
                    <div class="resultCount">
                    <?php global $wp_query;echo $wp_query->found_posts.' RESULTS';?>
                    </div>
           <div class="row">
            <?php   

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           $the_query->the_post();?>
         <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="cp-shadow cp-seeSinglePostWrapper">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                    <div class="bg-white single-post-box">
                    <div class="d-flex cp-CategoryList">
                     <div class="seeDate"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?></div>
                        <div class="cp_cat_list">
                            <?php $cat = get_the_category();
                            ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $cat[0]->term_id ) );?>"><?php echo $cat[0]->cat_name?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="cp-b-content"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 12, '...'); ?></a></h2></div>
                        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 25, '...'); ?></p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
             <?php }?>

            <?php 

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting terms as array:

```
'terms' => array($getSearch)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found my answer before 2 hours ago.

Comment: If you have time then can you help me out here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354486/search-not-working-with-title-and-content

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found my answer. I don't know this is the best way or know but it's solved my issue.

I tried below code in search.php

```
$getSearch = get_search_query();
$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'any',
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', //for tag
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array($getSearch),
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category', // for category
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array($getSearch),
    ),
  ),
]);
if ($query -> have_posts()):
  while ($query -> have_posts()) {
    $query -> the_post();
  } ?>
```