# Search not working with title and content

Tags: posts, search

I am working on search. I am able to search post by tag and category but not able to search by title and content.

I tried below code but it's not working. Would you help me out?

```
$getSearch = get_search_query();
//print($search);
$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
       array(
      's'=> $getSearch // for title and content
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', //for tag
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array($getSearch),
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category', // for category
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array($getSearch),
    ),
  ),
]); 

if ($query->have_posts() ):
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) {$query->the_post();?>
<!--some content-->
<?php }
else :
       get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
        endif;
?>
```

?>

**function.php**

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_exclude' );
function my_search_exclude( $query ) {
  if ( ! $query->is_admin && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'product' ) );
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 471 ) );
     $taxquery=  array(
  'post_type' => 'any',
  's'=> $query->get('s')
);
$query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery);

  }
}
```

Comment: Hello!  i see your `tax_query` has a post_type and an `s` value, this is extremely unusual and is not what  the docs  say goes in a `tax_query`. The `tax_query`  parameter only has taxonomy related items in it, why have you put the `s` and `post_type` parameters inside it? The docs never say to  do this, and have examples that say otherwise

Comment: @TomJNowell, I thought 's' is use for thr title and content search so I used. I am still confused what code I have to use fir title and content

Comment: `s` is just a generic search term parameter for the built in WP search, it's not a reusable generic field, you can't search taxonomy terms that way, the `s` parameter only goes in a single place. See the official doc on `WP_Query` for how to use the parameters https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#search-parameters, you can't just add an `s` parameter to a `tax_query` to search tags/categories/etc, same goes for `meta_query`, it's much more involved than that. If it's just search the post title and content, then use the `s` parameter as documented

Comment: @TomJNowell, Yes, I am checking this link from last 3 days but still I am trying to solve this.

Comment: I used the above query because I have to search the product by tag and category. Now tag and category working but title and content not working

Comment: True search of category and tag names in `WP_Query` is not possible. There is no way to change the parameters to make it work, the above query cannot be "fixed"

Comment: @TomJNowell, Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** It appears your actual problem is searching tags and categories, hence placing the `s` parameter inside the `tax_query`.

There is no way to search tags categories and other terms using only the fields provided by `WP_Query`. Your query doesn't work because what you want isn't possible with just the parameters available.

Instead of asking how to fix your solution/attempt, I'd recommend asking a new question for how to search taxonomy terms/categories/tags

---

*Original answer:*

The reason your search doesn't work, is because your query has no search:

```php
$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
       array(
      's'=> $getSearch // for title and content
    ),
...
```

For some reason, the `s` parameter has been inserted inside the `tax_query`, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

For example, here is a normal query that searches:

```php
$query = new WP_Query([
  's' => 'search terms',
etc..
```

But for some reason you've put it inside the `tax_query`:

```php
$query = new WP_Query([
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
       array(
          's'=> $getSearch // for title and content
       ),
```

This will not work, and is not what the documentation and examples suggest.

What's more, the code is creating a brand new query unnecessarily, which also doesn't make sense as it doubles the page loading time, and breaks pagination.

Instead, all these issues can be bypassed trivially by using the `pre_get_posts` filter, e.g. in `functions.php`:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q ) {
    if ( !$q->is_main_query() || !$q->is_search() ) {
        return;
    }
    $q->set( 'tax_query', ....... );
} );
```

Now you can use `search.php` as intended, with a standard post loop, and everything would work as it normally does. No need for a query at the top of the file.

The TLDR: If you want to change the posts WP shows, tell WP what you want via `pre_get_posts`. Don't create a second query, it cripples performance and introduces lots of new problems

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @Tom, I added function.php search code. I need to know what code I have to use inside     $q->set( 'tax_query', ....... ); ?

Comment: @NarenVerma the second parameter is the same as what you would put in the arguments array. I won't update my answer with a copy pasta but beginner level PHP should be enough to figure out what goes in there ( it should be a simple copy paste operation ). Also, none of this will work as long as you still have the `WP_Query` loop in your template, it needs to be changed for a standard post  loop

Comment: Trust me  I haven't understood your solution so I updated my code in the question. I am confused what code  I have to use inside function

Comment: @NarenVerma I suspect you don't have a basic grasp of PHP? Note that I won't be adding a copy paste solution to my answer, a beginner level understanding of PHP is necessary to understand any answers you get here

Comment: I need to know the answer so that i will understand where I am doing the mistake. I am trying to learn PHP and wordpress.

Comment: Yes, I added  inside the tax_query: because I have to search product by tag and category as well. so I thought.

Comment: That's not how that works, if you want to extend the WP search functionality to search taxonomies you'll either need to install a plugin to do that, or, make extensive code changes. You can't do that by changing a parameter in the query

Comment: I can't use a plugin that's the reason I tried from my side.

Comment: Is there a particular reason? Note that whatever you do will make your site slower, wether it's in a plugin or in the theme. The reason having lots of plugins makes you site slow isn't because plugins are slow, it's because doing more stuff takes more time. Eitherway you should ask a new question for how to search category and taxonomy terms, but keep in mind the answer will require basic/beginner programming skills, it would be much easier for you to find a plugin. WP search is not good, there's not much you can do to improve it

Comment: Actually, my boss doesn’t want it. And I already ask question search category and taxonomy and I tried that which is working but title and content search not working

Comment: If you have a time then please check this answer. I tried from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59300576/search-the-product-by-tag-or-category-not-working

Comment: I had a look, that Q belongs on this stack, not stackoverflow

Comment: whatever I understand, I added in the question. So there is no way to solve this issue except plugin right?

Comment: It can't be done by changing the stuff you pass to `WP_Query`, it requires custom code. Also you should edit your question, as the title of the question has nothing to do with your problem